# Generating keys for RSA dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, rsa, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm attempting to import an RSA Public key into dotnet with the following:

```
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(PublicKey), out _);
```

key was was generated with:

```
openssl genrsa -out name_of_private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in name_of_private_key.pem -pubout > name_of_public_key.pem
```

output:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtZL7iKRPSxrCflER6j/I
wB9fODXJgfxR4UBSU3oUJ8tIaBBnDrcutfXDfc7lZ9HcCZccvUsMzFKGJuvHthCE
/LNJmZtRRd02aLynoZSWqDBerCdRqXHbecMfK8KPxQSsWfinNiyFG76vTX2+V8P6
t4Cu8bM8j7foSBgOmECCSOjTuCG4bvKVS3bnu2lSBNgCjEMltk9W/3oSzKbN/mwn
GfViaXU5a1Zps3jLbx/z58o3Sb25QfQKU4xeohcx+Wj6d14lI80RErS1QTqSQ1rz
10Cs/Q1MudWstckqyE/u048GtXzQCzQOe4hWlyrcFqfiEAbV2jPLU61oer4/wT+0
7QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

However this returns

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: ASN1 corrupted data.
```

To import the key I'm taking the text between the headers and removing newlines, nothing else.  I have noticed that `rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo` DOES appear to work, however I'm not attempting to generate an X.509 key, I would like a PKCS#1 key so I can use the code above.

Guessing I've messed up the openssl commands?

Comment: Replace `-pubout` with `-RSAPublicKey_out` in your statement. To convert the X.509/SPKI key afterwards use `openssl rsa -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out -in <x509.pem> -out <public_pkcs1.pem>`

Comment: Getting some strange syntax errors. Do you mind a full sample?  Also make as answer so you get the points.

Comment: Sure, please see my answer.

Comment: *...I'm not attempting to generate an X.509 key...* There's nothing about that call that has much of anything to do with an "X.509 key". That's simply the format of the public key as defined in RFC 5280, and that format is arguably more standard and interoperable than the "PKCS #1" you seem to prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the posted X.509/SPKI key to a PKCS#1 public key using the following OpenSSL statement:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out -in name_of_public_key.pem > name_of_public_key_conv_pkcs1.pem
```

This returns the following key for *name_of_public_key_conv_pkcs1.pem*:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAtZL7iKRPSxrCflER6j/IwB9fODXJgfxR4UBSU3oUJ8tIaBBnDrcu
tfXDfc7lZ9HcCZccvUsMzFKGJuvHthCE/LNJmZtRRd02aLynoZSWqDBerCdRqXHb
ecMfK8KPxQSsWfinNiyFG76vTX2+V8P6t4Cu8bM8j7foSBgOmECCSOjTuCG4bvKV
S3bnu2lSBNgCjEMltk9W/3oSzKbN/mwnGfViaXU5a1Zps3jLbx/z58o3Sb25QfQK
U4xeohcx+Wj6d14lI80RErS1QTqSQ1rz10Cs/Q1MudWstckqyE/u048GtXzQCzQO
e4hWlyrcFqfiEAbV2jPLU61oer4/wT+07QIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Alternatively, you can generate a PKCS#1 public key *directly* using the following OpenSSL statements:

```
openssl genrsa -out name_of_private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in name_of_private_key.pem -RSAPublicKey_out > name_of_public_key_pkcs1.pem
```

Public keys in PKCS#1 format can be imported with the code you posted, e.g.

```cs
var PublicKey = @"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
                MIIBCgKCAQEAtZL7iKRPSxrCflER6j/IwB9fODXJgfxR4UBSU3oUJ8tIaBBnDrcu
                tfXDfc7lZ9HcCZccvUsMzFKGJuvHthCE/LNJmZtRRd02aLynoZSWqDBerCdRqXHb
                ecMfK8KPxQSsWfinNiyFG76vTX2+V8P6t4Cu8bM8j7foSBgOmECCSOjTuCG4bvKV
                S3bnu2lSBNgCjEMltk9W/3oSzKbN/mwnGfViaXU5a1Zps3jLbx/z58o3Sb25QfQK
                U4xeohcx+Wj6d14lI80RErS1QTqSQ1rz10Cs/Q1MudWstckqyE/u048GtXzQCzQO
                e4hWlyrcFqfiEAbV2jPLU61oer4/wT+07QIDAQAB
                -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----".
                Replace("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "").
                Replace("-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "").
                Replace("\r\n", "");
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(PublicKey), out _);

RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(parameters.Exponent, true, true)); // 65537
Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(parameters.Modulus, true, true));  // 22921612997464368147681940553984745387167552018036344531503795467063837226615581953768444015539628345845035732103113334279875993301411098168640007990192163617624452836576802897196284289413557038039593995983320236405640276117810563150914793233680115042600127677172037054986051882799772185194759951925398974095268701931531156047608941244890064857847352301510189736406400522269201574332107656671336685945934753045233371160604896169352804846566979618872110365310073347596127824815830796826711019699206801083371733500629381548849681219453339114997443300562712444634750316194264179142382642144192449752430619501209065600237
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  You said it was SQL but I managed to just run from the command line.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @m.edmondson - Thanks, must have been a mental lapse, I meant _OpenSSL_ of course. Fixed it.